# error when forward engineering MySQL model

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, workbench

I have created a model in MySQL workbench, when I want to forward engineer it to create the "create" and "insert" script I get the following error:

ERROR:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1366: Incorrect integer value: 'G1' for column 'gebruiker_id' at row 1
SQL Code:
        INSERT INTO `databaseher`.`gebruiker` (`gebruiker_id`, `voornaam`, `achternaam`, `E-mail`) VALUES ('G1', 'Ronny', 'Giezen', 'r.giezen@gmail.com')
```

I don't understand whats wrong with it, because the datatype of the column where the value "G1" inserts into is "VARCHAR(4)". It should be possible to insert both a letter and a number.... At least that's what I thought...

This is the create table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `databaseher`.`gebruiker` (
  `gebruiker_id` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  `voornaam` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `achternaam` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `E-mail` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gebruiker_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `E-mail_UNIQUE` (`E-mail` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

If someone could help, that'll be awesome.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess here because we don't have the full picture.
Can you run this:

```
Drop table 'databaseher'.'gebruiker'
```

And after recreate the table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `databaseher`.`gebruiker` (
  `gebruiker_id` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  `voornaam` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `achternaam` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `E-mail` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gebruiker_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `E-mail_UNIQUE` (`E-mail` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

rerun the insert.
I am guessing that the table was initially created with the column gebruiker as integer